# Need some help of a function in R

Tags: r

The question is: Create a function that takes in a numeric vector. The output should be a vector with running mean values. The i-th element of the output vector should be the mean of the values in the input vector from 1 to i.

My main problem is in the for loop, which is as follows:

```
  x1 <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
  for (i in 2: length(x1)){
       ma <- sum(x1[i-1] , x1[i]) / i
       print(ma)
       mresult <- rbind(ma)
  }
  View(ma)
```

I know there must be something wrong in it. But I am just not sure what it is.

Comment: `?mapply` try `mapply(function(i) mean(x1[1:i]), 1:length(x1))`. To make good use of R you need to learn the `apply` functions

Comment: alternatively, i think `cumsum(x1)/(1:length(x1))` also works

Comment: Someone already did this for you: `dplyr::cummean`

Comment: ^ Let's install and load a whole package for something we can do with one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noticed there are more efficient ways using already available functions and packages to achieve what you are trying to do. But here is how you would go about fixing your loop

```
x1 <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
mresult = numeric(0) #Initiate mresult. Or maybe you'd want to initiate with 0
for (i in 2: length(x1)){
    ma <- sum(x1[1:i])/i #You were originally dividing the sum of (i-1)th and ith value by i
    print(ma) #This is optional
    mresult <- c(mresult,ma) #Since you have only an array, there is no need to rbind
}
View(ma) #The last computed average
View(mresult) #All averages
```

Comment: Thank you! After reviewing my code compared with yours, I finally find out why I was wrong. Much appreciated!